# Getting selected value from DropDownList in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

An article view model

```
 public class ArticleViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose the language")]
        public BELocale Locale { get; set; }
}

public class BELocale : BEEntityBase
    {

        public string OriginalName { get; set; }
        public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
        public string TwoLetterISOName { get; set; }
    }
```

A view "AddLocaleForArticle"

```
@model Models.ArticleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("VefifyAddingLocaleForArticle", "Administration"))
{

 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { disabled = "disabled" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Locale,
                    new SelectList(ViewBag.AvalaibleLocales, "ID", "OriginalName"),   "Select a language"
               )
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Locale)
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />         
}
```

An action

```
public ActionResult VefifyAddingLocaleForPhoto(ArticleViewModel article)
        {
            //article.Locale == null for some reason.
             //but article.Title isn't null, it contains the data
            return RedirectToAction("AddingLocaleForPhotoSuccess", "adminka");
        }
```

Why article.Locale is equal null and how to fix it?

Comment: Check the name of your dropdownlist in HTML

Comment: The name is "Locale" in HTML.

Comment: "ID" doesn't seem to be present in your viewmodel

Comment: ViewModelBase and BEEntityBase contain ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the form is submitted a dropdown list sends only the selected value to the controller. So you cannot expect it to populate an entire complex object such as `BELocale` using a dropdownlist. The best you could is to populate its ID property and fetch the remaining of the object from your data store using this id.

So you will have to modify your dropdownlist helper so that it is bound to the id property of the locale as first argument:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Locale.ID,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.AvalaibleLocales, "ID", "OriginalName"),   
    "Select a language"
)
```

Now inside the corresponding controller action you will get the id:

```
public ActionResult VefifyAddingLocaleForPhoto(ArticleViewModel article)
{
    // article.Locale.ID will contain the selected locale id
    // so you can use this information to fetch the corresponding BELocale object
    ...
}
```

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", new SelectList(ViewBag.lstCountry, "CountryID", "CountryName"))`. On selecting a particular country, I want to pass the `CountryID` to the **countroller**. How can it be done using *jQuery*? **NOTE:** I'm **not** using *Strongly typed View*

Answer (score 0):

You may fill dropdown like this in your view model

```
public List<KeyValuePair<int, String>> locale
        {
            get
            {
               return  _localerepo.Findlocals().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.ID, x.OriginalName)).ToList();
            }
        }
```

In your view use this

```
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(Model.locale, "key", "value"), "--Select locale--")%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)%>
```